Tailwind CSS Drawer (offcanvas) - Flowbite toggle using React usestate
Maybe this is not the right way, if so please advice, but
I'm trying to use Flowbite drawer on my react vite typescript application. https://flowbite.com/docs/components/drawer/
the barebone that I can trigger is the following code
  return (
    <>
      <button type="button" data-drawer-target="drawer-example" data-drawer-show="drawer-example">
        Show Button
      </button>

      <div id="drawer-example" className="fixed top-0 left-0 z-40 h-screen p-4 overflow-y-auto transition-transform -translate-x-full bg-white w-80 dark:bg-gray-800" tabIndex={-1} aria-labelledby="drawer-label">
        test
      </div>
    <>

My question is how does the button work without onClick()?
My usecase really is to trigger the toggle using React.useState(), so I can do it programmatically, without having to click the button.
so ideally something like
const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false)
<div id="drawer-example" visible={visible}>

